# How to make sparkR run

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I have been trying to make SparkR work without success.
Read previous questions, blogs, and yet haven't been able to make it work.

First I had issues installing SparkR, finally I think I installed it, but then cannot make it run.
Here is my detailed code with different Options I tried to make it run.

Currently using Rstudio with R 3.6.0 version.
Any help will be appreciated!!

```
#***************************#
#Installing Spark Option 1
#***************************#
install.packages("SparkR")

'''
Does not work
'''

Sys.setenv("JAVA_HOME" = "D:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181")
Sys.getenv("JAVA_HOME")

#***************************#
#Installing Spark Option 2
#***************************#
#Find Spark Versions
jsonlite::fromJSON("https://api.github.com/repos/apache/spark/tags")$name


if (!require('devtools')) install.packages('devtools')
devtools::install_github('apache/spark@v2.4.6', subdir='R/pkg')

Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME='D:/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7')
.libPaths(c(file.path(Sys.getenv('SPARK_HOME'), 'R', 'lib'), .libPaths()))

'''
Installation didnt work
'''

#***************************#
#Installation Spark Option 3
#***************************#

install.packages("sparklyr")
library(sparklyr)
spark_install(version = "2.3.1")


install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/SparkR/SparkR_2.3.0.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
library(SparkR)

'''
One of 2 installations worked
'''

#***************************#
#Starting Spark Option 1
#***************************#

library(SparkR, lib.loc = c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R","lib")))
sparkR.session(master = "local[*]", sparkConfig = list(spark.driver.memory = "2g"))

'''
Spark package found in SPARK_HOME: D:/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7
Launching java with spark-submit command D:/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit2.cmd   --driver-memory "2g" sparkr-shell C:\Users\FELIPE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpKOxYkx\backend_port34a0263f43f5 
Error in if (len > 0) { : argumento tiene longitud cero
'''

#***************************#
#Starting Spark Option 2
#***************************#
Sys.setenv("JAVA_HOME" = "D:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181")
Sys.getenv("JAVA_HOME")

sparkEnvir <- list(spark.num.executors='5', spark.executor.cores='5')
# initializing Spark context
sc <- sparkR.init(sparkHome = "'D:/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7'",
                  sparkEnvir = sparkEnvir)

'''
Error in sparkR.sparkContext(master, appName, sparkHome, convertNamedListToEnv(sparkEnvir),  : 
  JVM is not ready after 10 seconds
Además: Warning message:
sparkR.init is deprecated.
Use sparkR.session instead.
See help("Deprecated") 
'''

#***************************#
#Starting Spark Option 3
#***************************#
Sys.setenv("JAVA_HOME" = "D:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181")
Sys.getenv("JAVA_HOME")

sparkEnvir <- list(spark.num.executors='5', spark.executor.cores='5')
# initializing Spark context
sc <- sparkR.session(sparkHome = "'D:/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7'",
                  sparkEnvir = sparkEnvir)

'''
Spark not found in SPARK_HOME: D:/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7
Spark package found in SPARK_HOME: D:/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7
Launching java with spark-submit command D:/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit2.cmd   sparkr-shell C:\Users\FELIPE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpKOxYkx\backend_port34a082b15e1 
Error in if (len > 0) { : argumento tiene longitud cero
'''
```

Comment: Any particular reason for trying version 2.3.1?